# Eager Loading on Self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Reader.rb

```
has_many :book_readers, dependent: :destroy
has_many :books, -> { where('published_at < ?', Time.zone.now) },
       through: :book_readers

after_create :assign_available_books

def assign_available_books
  self.books += Book.available_to_new_readers
end
```

Book.rb

```
has_many :book_readers, dependent: :destroy
has_many :readers, through: :book_readers

def self.available_to_new_readers
  where(available_to_new:true)
    .includes(:readers)
    .select{ |a| a.readers.any? }
end
```

book_reader.rb

```
class BookReader < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :book, uniqueness: { scope: :reader }

  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :reader
end
```

readers_controller.rb

```
def create
  if create_reader
    redirect_to [:admin, :readers], notice: 'Created reader successfully'...
end
...
def create_reader
  reader_attributes = reader_params.clone
  admin_attributes = reader_attributes.delete(:reader_admin_attributes) || {}
  save_reader_and_admin(reader_attributes, admin_attributes)
end
...
def save_reader_and_admin(reader_attributes, admin_attributes)
  @reader, success = Reader.new(reader_attributes), false
  @reader.transaction do
    @reader.save || raise(ActiveRecord::Rollback)
    @reader.build_reader_admin(admin_attributes.merge(reader: @reader))
    @reader.reader_admin.save || raise(ActiveRecord::Rollback)
    @reader.save || raise(ActiveRecord::Rollback)
    success = true
  end
  success
end
```

[Bullet Gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) Message on Page Loading:

```
USE eager loading detected
  Reader => [:books]
  Add to your finder: :includes => [:books]
Call stack
 app/models/reader.rb:94:in `assign_available_books'
 app/controllers/admin/readers_controller.rb:67:in `block in save_reader_and_admin'
 app/controllers/admin/readers_controller.rb:66:in `save_reader_and_admin'
 app/controllers/admin/readers_controller.rb:61:in `create_reader'
 app/controllers/admin/readers_controller.rb:18:in `create'
```

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to eager load on `self` in the assign_available_books method. I've tried appending `.includes(:books)` to that but I get `undefined method includes`.

Comment: Can you show the `readers_controller.rb`?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Yep. Have updated.

Comment: You know, `@reader.save!` does the same trick as `@reader.save || raise(ActiveRecord::Rollback)`